# Building Module for Azure Automation Account in C#

Tags: c#, azure-automation, azure-authentication

I am trying to create a C# CmdLet that approximates the following Powershell commands: -

```
$myCred = Get-AutomationPSCredential -Name $Automation_Credentials
$userName = $myCred.UserName
$password = $myCred.GetNetworkCredential().Password
```

so I can then do the equivalent of

```
$prep = [System.Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(${authpair})    
$base64 = [System.Convert]::ToBase64String(${prep})    
$basicAuthValue = "Basic $base64"
```

and then

```
Invoke-RestMethod
```

I see to have fallen at the very 1st hurdle of what is the equivalent of the

```
Get-AutomationPSCredential -Name $Automation_Credentials
```

in a C# Cmdlet.

The skeleton C# CmdLet looks as follows: -

```
namespace MyNamespace
{
    using System.Management.Automation;

    [Cmdlet(VerbsCommunications.Connect, "Ka")]
    public class ConnectKa
        : Cmdlet
    {
        /// <summary>
        ///     The base URL  e.g. http://localhost:8081
        /// </summary>
        [Parameter (Position = 0, 
            HelpMessage="The base URL e.g. http://localhost:8081",
            Mandatory= true)]
        public string BaseUrl { get; set; } = null;

        /// <summary>
        ///     The name of the Cluster to authenticate against
        ///     (not necessarily the cluster we are running the commands against).
        /// </summary>
        [Parameter (Position = 1, 
            HelpMessage="The name of the Cluster to authenticate against (not necessarily the cluster " +
                        "we are running the commands against).",
            Mandatory= true)]
        public string Cluster_Name { get; set; } = null;

        [Parameter (Position = 2, 
            HelpMessage="The name of the Azure AutomationAccount to log in with.",
            Mandatory= true)]
        public string Automation_Credentials { get; set; } = null;

        /// <summary>
        ///     Perform Cmdlet processing.
        /// </summary>
        protected override void ProcessRecord()
        {
            // Need to perform the equivalent of the following Powershell
            //  $myCred = Get-AutomationPSCredential -Name $Automation_Credentials
            //  $userName = $myCred.UserName
            //  $password = $myCred.GetNetworkCredential().Password  
            //  $authpair = "${userName}:${password}" 
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: "fallen" is not a problem statement, what error are you getting? Where is `$Automation_Credentials` coming from?

Comment: I am getting no error as I am trying to write the C# equivalent. The Powershell code I have works fine and the $Automation_Credentials is a [Parameter] to the Powershell function. It is the translation of this code to the equivalent C# Azure SDK is my challenge as I cannot work out how to obtain the credentials for the AutomationAccount using the account name.

Comment: We cannot help you fix your c# without seeing your c#.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Get-AutomationPSCredential command in Azure Automation is special: its implementation uses platform internals to retrieve secrets properly. You don't want to duplicate this code: it is relatively complicated, and your copy may stop working any time, as it would rely on interfaces between internal components, which can change any time without notice.

If you want to do something on top of what Get-AutomationPSCredential does, a better idea would be to invoke the original Get-AutomationPSCredential command, capture the output, and perform your additional processing.

Comment: To clarify, all I am asking is that if  `Get-AutomationPSCredential`is the Powershell command what is the translation of that one call to a pre-built Microsoft C# SDK that I can call. I do not want to rebuild it I am just looking for that translation, like an equivalent to Goole Translate for API calls. Or are we saying there is no published way from a C# CMDLet to log in to an AzureAutomation account, using a Microsoft C# SDK, but only by the CMDLet calling out to a Powershell script?

Comment: @Jock This is exactly my point: there is no such translation. The `Get-AutomationPSCredential` implementation uses Automation platform internals that are not exposed via any published SDK. In theory, you can reverse-engineer this implementation, but then again: it relies on the internals that are not a part of any public contract, so they can change any time without notice, breaking your code as a result. These internals do not even _need_ Automation Account credentials because they already "know" which context they are running in.

Comment: Thank you for that clarification appreciated. Also explains why in the few hours I did searching for an answer online, that I did not find one :)